# Is the difference mentioned between API and DLL correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a Project contains following

1. Presentation Layer
2. Data Access Layer(Abstract) DLL
3. Business Logic Layer        DLL
4. Sql Server layer            DLL

All these DLL are part of the project.  In case I prepare a Web Service or WCF project and deploy it in some other web server and access the service from Presentation layer by keeping the dll above mentioned in this new server. Will it becomes an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any public method of any assembly or class is API. I think, I know what you mean, even though your question is not formed correctly.
I think, you mean, you want to move your DLLs to a service layer and have presentation talk to the service rather than DLLs directly. Well, the good news is, this is fairly easy. For example, if you use classic XML web service, you can create Web Service project in which you can wrap your APIs into Web Methods and in your presentation will need to [preferably] write adapters to pull data from Dll API or Web Service, depending to which you're connected to. Of course, you can just replace calls to Dlls with calls to Web Methods - this can be super simple. 
With WCF you will need to define service contracts and there will be more changes on the client (presentation layer). 
But there will need to have some layer of security to be added. You're on the web now, remember?

Comment: I am trying to learn difference between them and want to confirm that is my example correct ?

Comment: Your example is correct. In your example you have at least 3 layers of APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Who knows?

An [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) can take many forms. Basically it's a kind of interface one part of your system talks to another part. This interface can be *implemented* in a DLL, or not in a DLL, or partly in a DLL, or in several DLLs.

Comment: can you please give a simple example about API? I meant, if you have to explain somebody about it , how will you do that. thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, WPF and WCF are types of APIs - albeit rather large APIs.

Comment: A method being called by your presentation layer from your business logic layer is API. Everything you can call from your code is API, regardless, if this is within your system, on your local machine or comes from remote server.